# Entity Framework - how to handle Nullable in entity

Tags: entity-framework, nullable

I have an entity(EF) with property int? priority.

I want to work with the entity across my platform.

```
Dictionary<int, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<int,Task>();
tasks.Add(task.Priority, task);
```

in the second row, I want to get `Priority` out of task and fire it an `int`. but I get an error that `int?` is not `int`, which is true.

How to handle this situation

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) witch gets the value of the current Nullable value.

But be aware to the [HasValue Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) so you can provide a default value in case its false.

Comment: You can also use the ?? operator.